# Event is not triggering for File Upload - Worklight

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing mobile application through IBM Worklight. Our current worklight server version is 6.2.0.01 and cordova version is 3.4.

We are facing issue with below code.

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>

<img id='output'>

<script>

  var openFile = function(event) {

    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(){

      var dataURL = reader.result;

      var output = document.getElementById('output');

      output.src = dataURL;

    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

  };
</script>
```

Worklight server 6.3 and cordova 3.6.3  - **Working fine.**

Worklight server 6.2.0.01 and cordova 3.4 - **Not Working** **(giving error message: "A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed." name: "NotFoundError")**

Comment: Have you updated to the latest available iFix for 6.2 from IBM Fix Central to make sure you have the latest Cordova patches that may have been applied to it? What is your 6.2 build number?

Comment: So, if it doesn't work on Worklight server 6.2 - cordova 3.4, but it works on Worklight server 6.3 - cordova 3.6.3, there was a bug that has been fixed. Why don't you use Worklight server 6.3 and cordova 3.6.3?

Comment: Idan - our current worklight server version is 6.2.0.01. I am only facing this issue with Android 5.0 version.

jcesar - our problem is everything we tested for worklight 6.2 but now if we change to 6.3 then we have to retest everything.

Comment: @user3885468, I asked for the build number - 6.2.0.01-201506004 - that's the build number (Find it in Eclipse > About > Worklight). Regardless, go to IBM Fix Central website and download the Latest 6.2 iFix for Studio as it may contain a backport fix for Cordova for you issue. If it's still happening for you and you must use 6.2, then open a PMR (support ticket), but as mentioned by jcesarmobile, your version is old and you should upgrade to 6.3 and maybe even 7.0.

Comment: Idan - My build number is 6.2.0.01.20150214.

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be a Cordova issue, the only way to fix it is by opening a PMR (support ticket), asking IBM to investigate and back-port a fix from Cordova 3.6 back into Cordova 3.4 that is being used by Worklight 6.2.

Comment: We have upgraded worklight version 6.2.0.01 to 7.0. Its working fine for android and bb device. But facing issue with iOS build. If we open the app in iphone device app is crashing. 

Its giving error:-

[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0:-2'
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host